# Using Jira to trigger a Jenkins build

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-jira-trigger

I have a strange use case here I know, but basically I have a CI / CD solution that starts be a developer creating a zip file of a set of resources. This zip is then sucked in to SVN via the tools internal programs.

Currently the solution works, using the FSTRigger to poll for an updated zip. When it see it, then the process kicks off and we're happy.

going forward I'd like the builds to be triggered by a Jira job reaching a certain status and have been looking at the Jira trigger plugin. It looks like it will help satisfy me with regards the triggering of the build and passing data from Jira to Jenkins to use for delivery notes etc. However it would still depend on the zip file being in a certain location to be picked up.

I'm wondering if it's possible to attach the zip to the Jira task and then as part of the task status hitting 'build' kick off the Jenkins job and copy the zip so it can be picked up by by the Jenkins build task.

for reasons to complex to mention, checking the zip into svn first won't really work.

Answer (score 1):

When your Jenkins build is triggered via jira-trigger-plugin, you would be able to access `JIRA_ISSUE_KEY` environment variable that contains the JIRA issue which status has changed.

With the JIRA issue key, you can hit [Get Issue JIRA REST API](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/server/#api/2/issue-getIssue) to retrieve the issue details. The issue details would contain the attachment information, which would then be able to be used for downloading the zip in Jenkins.